# How are Akka messages ordered if messages are not reliable?

Tags: scala, akka

I read that Akka messages are ordered in that between any two actors A and B, if A sends messages in order 1, 2, 3, 4, they must arrive in that order.

Also I read that Akka messages are not reliable.

How can these two things be true? If message arrives 1 and then 4 and then 3, but 2 was never delivered, then what happens?

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/message-delivery-reliability.html

---

To clarify, if messages 1 2 3 and 4 exist and are sent in that order from actor A.

Lets consider these are points a), b), c) d).

a) At actor B, message 1 arrives.

b) Then at actor B message 4 arrives.

c) Then at actor B message 3 arrives.

d) Message 2 was lost.

At point a) I see no problem, actor B processes the message.

At point b) I see a problem, how can actor B process this message 4 because of message ordering rules, actor B is expecting message 2 to arrive. So I guess at this point actor B cannot process message 4 as message 4 cannot be processes before message 2.

At point c) message 3 has arrived, but we cannot process message 3 without message 2 due to ordering.

At point d) Message 2 has been lost.

So the actor B will only process message 1 and will not process messages 3 and 4, if I apply the rules as I understand them. Is my logic correct? Am I making an incorrect assumption here by assuming that messages could arrive at actor B in any order. However, if two actors are on the internet, shouldn't that be the case? If its fire-and-forget for the message?

Comment: The order of messages that are delivered is still the order in which they were sent, so there's no contradiction.

Comment: This question is valid. Nowhere in the docs is the scenario of "message 4 is delayed until after message 3" addressed. At least, it is not explained what *would* happen. All it says is that it does not.

Comment: What do you mean? Akka guarantees that the scenario does NOT happen, so the question of what would happen in that case is moot.

Comment: I don't understand how it can NOT happen although it says it cannot, the idea of messages not being reliable, messages can be lost and the ordering doesn't seem to work in my mind. I want to be able to model in my mind how it works.

Comment: What I mean is, its logically inconsistent if messages can be dropped.

Comment: @Phil: Am having the same doubts. If you understood how Akka guarantees message delivery order, could you post an answer here?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, what if messages are dropped? like A, B, C, then B fails to deliver and messages came in order B, A, ... well anyway, there's so many cases to consider, I don't understand how message ordering is guaranteed if message delivery is not guaranteed.

Comment: @Phil I have the same doubt. Did you find the answer ? I think there is no such guarantee as mentioned in the note section of akka docs
```
It is important to note that Akka’s guarantee applies to the order in which messages are enqueued into the recipient’s mailbox.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the documentation says, if actor `A1` sends messages `M1`, `M2` and `M3` to actor `A2`, those messages will be delivered in that order *relative to messages sent from `A1` to `A2`.  If `A3` is also sending messages to `A2`, there is no guarantee regarding how the messages from `A1` and `A3` will be interleaved.  A message from `A3` could arrive in-between two messages from `A1`.  Messages from `A1` would still be in order relative to other messages from `A1`.

So in your example, (1, 4, 3) is guaranteed not to happen.  (1, 3, 4) is valid since any message can be dropped but if 3 is delivered, it's guaranteed to be delivered before 4.

Comment: You say that (1,4,3) is guaranteed not to happen, how is that guaranteed? I don't see how it can be if messages are just sent, one message may take a lot longer time to travel through the internet than another message, so the ordering in which they arrive at B could be in any order?

Comment: Is my assumption that messages can get out of order incorrect? Secondly, you say "if 3 is delivered, its guaranteed to be delivered before 4", but what if 3 was lost and 4 arrived. So 4 is thrown away? or 4 is processed but that would break the rules.

Comment: Order of delivery of messages is guaranteed but within SAME Actor.
How could message #3 be lost? Of course receiving Actor doesn't know about the order so it won't throw away or not process message #4.

Comment: Any message can be lost, since akka implements at-most-once delivery.

Comment: I have a similar question - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39149858/how-does-akka-ensure-at-most-once-message-delivery. I don't see how akka can give guarantee not deliver a message twice or more.